# Architecture issue: Directives, css, scroll-events and dependencies

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a visual website with lots of stuff depending on the scroll position. I understood this isn't the ideal type of project for Angular. Since things are very interdependent, it makes it hard to isolate things. Nevertheless, I wanted to try and do this kind of project with Angular, hoping to learn a better way to create modular code.

I run into a structural problem that is similar with both scroll events and CSS:

I try to create my directives with less dependencies as possible towards each other. The result is that each directive that deals with the scroll has it's own listener to the scroll event. Maybe this is isn't so awful concerning performance (or is it?), but it makes it hard to know what happens first. In jQuery land I end up using one single $(window).bind('scroll, ..) function, putting all scroll logic in one place, then the order is clear.

Similarly, this modularity makes having one single CSS file awkward, ideally I'd like to set the CSS from inside the directive to encapsulate the behaviour.

I have a feeling there might be some best practices with these types of issues that I haven't found out about.

j

Comment: Have you thought about injecting a scroll service as a dependency into your directives?

Comment: thanks, (instantly start googling services)